# Irreducible representation of $O(n)$

Tags: representation-theory

Given a field $\mathbb{K}$ and $O(n)$ the orthogonal group given by rotation matrix in $\mathbb{K}^n$. How can I prove that every irreducible representation of $O(n)$ occurs in $(\mathbb{K}^n)^{\otimes r}$ for $r$ non negative integer?

Answer (score 0):

For complex representations and $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, these representations will basically be controlled by the representations of the Lie algebra. These are classified by highest weight, and you can find the highest weight representations in the spaces you list.

Comment: This is correct, but somehow the OP asks for a *proof*, while you are stating the facts...